# Errors using pdfx package to generate PDF/A

Tags: pdftex

I need to submit my thesis in PDF/A format. I am using LyX, but I don't think that is relevant for my question.

I get this error message when running `pdfx` package:

```
! pdfTeX error (ext5): cannot open file for embedding.
l.137 ...eam attr{/N 4}  file{sRGBIEC1966-2.1.icm}
```

The documentation says to put any color file in the `pdfx` folder and rename it to `sRGBIEC1966-2.1.icm`.

I have tried this and get the same error. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: How about just placing the file in your working folder (where your original `.tex` file is located)?

Comment: I've tried that also. Did not work. I download the color icc file from http://www.color.org/srgbprofiles.xalter and changed the filename to icm.

Comment: Then I suggest producing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that reproduces the problem so community members can work with something. Do this by exporting a *small* file you've created in LyX (...that replicates the problem) and posting that as part of your question via an [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/71224/edit).

Comment: And even when using a working ``pdfx``, [I was not able to get a compliant PDF/A document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57292/pdf-a-width-information-for-rendered-glyphs-is-inconsistent)

Answer (score 4):

- pdfTeX looks for the file with the name `sRGBIEC1966-2.1.icm` exactly. Depending on the operating system/file system also uppercase/lowercase matters. Renaming the file name extension from `.icc` to `.icm` is not enough, also the file name must match.
- If the file is put in the folder `pdfx`, then this folder is probably inside the `texmf` distribution tree (a better place would be a local/home tree). Then the file name database must be updated. `texhash`/`mktexlsr` in case of TeX Live and in case of MiKTeX the action must be done in admin mode (`Maintennance (Admin)`). Otherwise the file name databases for the system `texmf` tree is skipped and not updated.
- The program `kpsewhich` can be used on the command line in both TeX Live and MiKTeX to check, whether a file would be found by TeX:

  ```
  kpsewhich sRGBIEC1966-2.1.icm
  ```

  It should report the file name with the complete path.

Comment: Could you explain what `sRGBIEC1966-2.1.icm` is / does? I got it from https://github.com/bencomp/pdfx-ext/blob/master/sRGBIEC1966-2.1.icm and `file` says `Microsoft ICM Color Profile`, but I am on a Linux machine using TeXLive, so I wonder why I need it / what it is good for.

Comment: @moose Wikipedia page: [ICC profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile). The PDF/A standard requires a color profile to be embedded.