# Device Independent color

Tags: color, pdf-a

I am validating the following latex document with [The 3-Heights™ PDF Validator Online Tool](http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{blue}{This is only a test}
\end{document}
```

The output gives the error:

`A device-specific color space (DeviceRGB) without an appropriate output intent is used.`

How can I use colors that aren't device specific? Or use the appropriate intent?

Comment: The [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package lets you chose the color model, including device independent one.

Comment: @mafp I reviewed the documentation provided, which did mention driver-independent access to colors. Which color model is device independent(gray, rgb, HTML, etc.)?

Comment: I think it is already best explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9973/21591.

Comment: @mafp I agree that it has been explained there and in the pdf documentation. I was unable to find a working example that I could use for this scenario.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generating PDFA-1b compatible PDFs is rather difficult with LaTeX. The details are described here: http://support.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=Generating_PDF/A_compliant_PDFs_from_pdftex

If it is just about the color profile, you may use the following piece of code:

```
\pdfminorversion=4
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}

\immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 3}  file{sRGBIEC1966-2.1.icm}
\pdfcatalog{%
/OutputIntents [ <<
/Type /OutputIntent
/S/GTS_PDFA1
/DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
/OutputConditionIdentifier (sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
/Info(sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
>> ]
}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{blue}{This is only a test}
\end{document}
```

The file sRGBIEC1966-2.1.icm is the color profile you want to use. Please put this file into the same directory your tex document is, so it can be found by pdftex. If you want to make your PDF even more PDFA-1b compliant, you may want to have a look at the pdfx package which has an option for PDFA-1b, too.

http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/

Please note that PDFs generated by pdftex are not PDFA compatible due to wrong EOL markers.

Update: I just added a complete example that works just fine for me. Please note that I use PDF version 1.4 to prevent compressed streams.

Update2: You can download color profiles from here:

Adobe (SRGB and CMYK): http://www.adobe.com/digitalimag/adobergb.html

and here (SRGB) http://www.color.org/srgbprofiles.xalter

Comment: I tried adding the above code between the `\usepackage` and `\begin`, but then I got the error referred to in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71224/17290

Comment: Are you sure you have the color profile in the same directory of your tex document?

Comment: Wow, amazing. Never saw anything like that. So for a given file, how do I get the exact string that is "sRGB IEC61966-2.1" in this example? Any idea?

Comment: Ok, the answer seems to be: you google for your color profile and `OutputConditionIdentifier`.

Comment: Dunno if I get your question right, on Mac/Linux command line: strings FILENAME.pdf | grep sRGB

Comment: I was able to add the file from [github](https://github.com/bencomp/pdfx-ext/blob/master/sRGBIEC1966-2.1.icm), but when I validate using the Online Validation Tool it still mentions the device specific color. Were you able to validate the pdf online without this error?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code slightly /N 4 -> **/N 3**. Now it should work!

Comment: I just added two links were you can get a variety of color profiles. Please let me know if it works out.

Comment: It worked for me, but what is the significance of changing `/N 4` to `/N 3`?

Comment: You can find it in the PDF specs: "The number of color components in the color space described by the ICC profile data. This number must match the number of components actually in the ICC profile. As of PDF 1.4, N must be 1, 3, or 4."

Comment: I'm not sure though, but I would assume that 3 = RGB, 4=CMYK. That is a subtle error I fixed in my own version of the pdfx package.

Comment: For reference, your other [important answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99708/21591) shall be linked. And keep pushing this stuff, I am interested in it, too. E.g. you could upload your modified pdfx package to CTAN.