# Generating PDF/A-1b compliant documents using pdfx and pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, pdf, pdf-a

There are several discussions on the web on how to generate PDF/A-1b compliant documents.

One approach can be found on http://support.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=Generating_PDF/A_compliant_PDFs_from_pdftex which is implemented as far as I can see in the `pdfx` package.

I created a minimal `test.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx} 
\begin{document} 
Hello, world! 
\end{document}
```

From what I understand, I need to place metadata in a separate file called test.xmpdata:

```
\Title{PDF/A-Compliance}
\Author{Ada Lovelace}
\Org{TeX University}
\Keywords{PDF/A}
```

I compile `test.tex` using pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian).

For validation of PDF/A-1b compliancy, I use `jhove` and a PDF export from LibreOffice as a positive control.

```
jhove -m pdf-hul test.pdf
```

However, jhove laments

```
ErrorMessage: Lexical error
  Offset: 16530
```

So my `test.pdf` file does not seem to be PDF/A compliant.
Could you please give me hints on additional diagnostics to run in order to pin down the problem?

Comment: Interestingly, Adobe's Acrobat Reader shows a hint that the generated document would be PDF/A compliant. So maybe this is just a jhove problem. Could maybe someone who possesses Adobe's Acrobat Professional use the Preflight functionality to validate this? But at least `pdfinfo test.pdf` isn't showing the correct metadata either.

Comment: See also [How to create tagged PDF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/579) and [LaTeX accessibility](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19279)

Comment: See also [pdf/a: Width information for rendered glyphs is inconsistent](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57292)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments so far, but they didn't help me to solve the problem. The thread on width information for rendered glyphs might become important for me if I start using math fonts.

Comment: The pdfx CTAN package ships with the file small2e.pdf which shall presumably be PDF/A compliant. However, jhove tells me that this file is also not well formatted, because it contains a lexical error. Nevertheless, Adobe's Acrobat Reader shows a message claiming this file is viewed in PDF/A mode. Once again, if anyone of you has got a version of Adobe's Acrobat Professional, it would be interesting to see its Preflight comments on this file.

Comment: @PenguinNurse According to Acrobat X Pro's Preflight, [small2e.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/small2e.pdf) is not a valid PDF/A-1b. You can find a summary [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41227811/small2e_report.pdf).

Comment: @sebschub I would have interpreted "All problems according to Preflight profile Verify compliance with PDF/A-1b" that the file is verified to be complicent.

Comment: @Jörg The errors are listed on the first page. I suppose that nothing is marked on the second page because the errors cannot be pointed to a visible spot in the document.

Comment: @sebschub Ah, I did not realise that there is a page 1 :-)

Comment: I would like to add that since the OP mentions the instructions contained at <http://support.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=Generating_PDF/A_compliant_PDFs_from_pdftex>, it is important to note that the file `pdfa-1b.xmp` used by `pdfx.sty` (and contained in its directory) is different from the file `pdfa-1b.xmp` used in the instructions at [river-valley.com](<http://support.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=Generating_PDF/A_compliant_PDFs_from_pdftex). For example, the file `pdfa-1b.xmp` in the directory `pdfx.sty` makes use of the macro `\xmpKeywords` while the file `pdfa-1b.xmp`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### See updated solution

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/535849/50129

#### OUTDATED

Generating PDFA-1b compliant documents is not possible with the default pdftex. There is a minor bug in pdftex resulting in non-compliant EOL markers. There is a bug report from 2011 about this problem which successfully resolves the issue. You can find it here:

http://sarovar.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=4341&group_id=106&atid=493

There is also a file attached to this report:
http://sarovar.org/tracker/download.php/106/493/4341/10821/verify_this_sample.zip

It contains instructions on how to patch pdftex to generate PDFA-1b compatible files. The package also contains a patched version of pdfx. Unfortunately, these changes did not made it into the code base yet.

Comment: This is fixed in the latest Tex Live source! See [svn repo](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/pdftexdir/pdftex.web?r1=32319&r2=32428) and [mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-December/034573.html).

Comment: It seems that the link is not longer working....

Comment: This answer used to be correct at time of writing but it is completely wrong as of today. How to handle this? Flag down, delete or create a new answer? The problem is a high pagerank. For answers see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/535849/50129).

Answer (score 5):

I had to validate a document through `jhove`, and I managed to do it using [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) on the PDF that was produced by `pdflatex`. I simply used the command

```
pdftk MyDocument.pdf output ValidatedDocument.pdf
```

I hope it can help you!

Comment: Well, it would of course nice to create a compliant document directly from TeX or LaTeX. But the good thing about your solution is that it doesn't require proprietary software.

Comment: I totally agree (on both points!).

Comment: -1! This answer is misleading and thus, plain wrong! In no way does `pdftk` convert a non-PDF/A document into a PDF/A, nor does it really validate a PDF/A document. There is not even a hint in the `pdftk` documentation which suggests so.

Comment: I am sorry if this answer is misleading. Yet, I really used `pdftk` to produce a PDF file which was "validated" by `jhove` as I wrote. I am not sure the resulting PDF is a PDF/A, simply that it passed `jhove` tests so that my grad school accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a right answer to the question, but it might help someone who wants to generate a PDF/A (especially the *1b* version for archives) from a LaTeX project.

I tried the `pdfx` package, even though it helps to reduce the number of validation errors, veraPDF sill complaining about so many others.
The problem is LaTeX alone cannot check all the requirements (for example the transparency of the graphics).

After some research I found that [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) can be used to convert a PDF to PDF/A (see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659147/how-to-use-ghostscript-to-convert-pdf-to-pdf-a-or-pdf-x)), but the validation was not always successful as well. Some versions does not even work. Sometimes it works but the resulting PDF will have some issues (for example links does not work, metadata are removed, etc).

The idea then is to use the `pdfx` package, compile the project using pdfLaTeX then run Ghostscript on the resulting PDF and use a program like [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) to fix the metadata issue. This gave me good results (at least on my LaTeX thesis).

I wrote a simple script to automate the above process. Although I am not sure if it will work for every LaTeX project, but I hope it will help someone in the same situation.
The installation process as well as the source code are hosted on github: [latex2pdfa](https://github.com/abdeladim-s/latex2pdfa)

Comment: *Thank* *you* *so* *much*, this script is a pleasure to use, and worked flawlessly in my case.

Comment: You are welcome @Clément, 'Glad you found it useful :)